# How to create SASS such that classes with identical CSS are declared together with commas?

Tags: css, sass

Consider the SASS below.

```
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
.col-#{$i} {
position: relative;
}
}
```

It compiles to the following CSS.

```
.col-1 {
  position: relative;
}

.col-2 {
  position: relative;
}

.col-3 {
  position: relative;
}

.col-4 {
  position: relative;
}

.col-5 {
  position: relative;
}
```

But I would like it to compile like this.

```
.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3,
.col-4,
.col-5 {
  position: relative;
}
```

How can this be done? I feel it should become the way I need with a slightly different syntax but I can't figure it out. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@extend` to do what you want :

```
%relative {
  position: relative;
}

@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  .col-#{$i} {
    @extend %relative;
  }
}
```

You will get :

```
.col-5, .col-4, .col-3, .col-2, .col-1 {
  position: relative;
}
```

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/) is an explanation on how the `@extend` works. The `%` symbol is for `placeholder selectors`, it is useful if you don't want the extended selector (here `%relative`) to show up in your CSS.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, sorry

Comment: @happy No problem, I'm glad I was able to help. ^^